# Box2D weird behavior with std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, box2d, sfml, rigid-bodies

### lately I started playing with [box2d](https://github.com/erincatto/box2d) and tried abstracting it to class

```
RigidBody::RigidBody() {

}

RigidBody::RigidBody(const RigidBody& other) {
    m_fixture = other.m_fixture;

    b2BodyDef bodyDef;
    bodyDef.position = other.m_body->GetPosition();
    bodyDef.type = other.m_body->GetType();

    m_body = Runtime::PhysicsWorld.CreateBody(&bodyDef);

    b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
    fixtureDef.shape                = m_fixture->GetShape();
    fixtureDef.density              = m_fixture->GetDensity();
    fixtureDef.friction             = m_fixture->GetFriction();
    fixtureDef.restitution          = m_fixture->GetRestitution();
    fixtureDef.restitutionThreshold = m_fixture->GetRestitutionThreshold();

    m_fixture = m_body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);
}

RigidBody::RigidBody(sf::Vector2f pos, BodyType type) {
    pos /= Constants::PPM;

    b2BodyDef bodyDef;
    bodyDef.position = pos;
    bodyDef.type = (b2BodyType)type;

    m_body = Runtime::PhysicsWorld.CreateBody(&bodyDef);

    sf::Vector2f size(50.0f, 50.0f);

    size /= 2.0f;
    size /= Constants::PPM;

    b2PolygonShape shape;
    shape.SetAsBox(size.x, size.y);

    b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;

    fixtureDef.shape                = &shape;
    fixtureDef.density              = 1.0f;
    fixtureDef.friction             = 0.5f;
    fixtureDef.restitution          = 0.0f;
    fixtureDef.restitutionThreshold = 0.5f;

    m_body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);
}

RigidBody::~RigidBody() {
    Runtime::PhysicsWorld.DestroyBody(m_body);
}
```

but vector is behaving really weird with it i know it's probably becasue of copy constructor or destructor but I can't figure this out

```
std::vector<hv::RigidBody> m_Bodies;
```

the problem is with vector erase when I call m_Bodies.erase(m_Bodies.begin()) for some reason it deletes the last objects

```
m_Bodies.erase(m_Bodies.begin());
```

And after I call m_Bodies.erase(m_Bodies.begin()) second time I get this

[image: god help]

Also it doesn't matter how many objects is in vector if I call m_Bodies.erase(m_Bodies.begin() + 3) it will always delete the last one

*edit corrected question

Comment: Did you mean delete m_bodies.front() ? Otherwise erase the last element, not the first.

Comment: You `delete` the last element, then you remove the first element, leaving a pointer to the recently destroyed object last in the vector. If you ever dereference that pointer, all bets are off.

Comment: BTW: `v.erase(v.begin());` would be `v.pop_front()`, if it existed. You most likely want `delete m_Bodies.back(); m_Bodies.pop_back();`

Comment: oh shoot that's right but it dosen't resolve problem when not using pointer `std::vector<hv::RigidBody> m_Bodies` and then calling `m_Bodies.erase(m_Bodies.begin());` it throws exception shown in image above

Comment: Can you edit your question with the definition of `CreateBody` in text? I suspect that the stack-local address you're handing to that method is the culprit.

Comment: I would guess that you are missing a correctly defined `operator=`. When the first element of the vector is removed; in reality, all later elements are assigned to their prior element, and then the final element is deleted. Before being deleted, the old final element was assigned to the new final element, so if this assignment wasn't done correctly, it is possible that the new final element will be made invalid by the deletion of the old final element.

Comment: @Mankarse thanks a for your help it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I didn't define operator =
resolved it by

```
RigidBody* RigidBody::operator=(const RigidBody& other) {
    if(m_body)
        Runtime::PhysicsWorld.DestroyBody(m_body);

    m_fixture = other.m_fixture;

    b2BodyDef bodyDef;
    bodyDef.position = other.m_body->GetPosition();
    bodyDef.type = other.m_body->GetType();

    m_body = Runtime::PhysicsWorld.CreateBody(&bodyDef);

    b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
    fixtureDef.shape = m_fixture->GetShape();
    fixtureDef.density = m_fixture->GetDensity();
    fixtureDef.friction = m_fixture->GetFriction();
    fixtureDef.restitution = m_fixture->GetRestitution();
    fixtureDef.restitutionThreshold = m_fixture->GetRestitutionThreshold();

    m_fixture = m_body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);

    return this;
}
```